# How do you bulk index documents into the default mapping of ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, default, bulk

The documentation for ElasticSearch 5.5 offers no examples of how to use the bulk operation to index documents into the default mapping of an index.  It also gives no indication why this is *not* possible, unless I'm missing that somewhere else in the documentation.

The ES 5.5 documentation gives one explicit example of bulk indexing:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

But it also says that

> The endpoints are /_bulk, /{index}/_bulk, and {index}/{type}/_bulk.
>   When the index or the index/type are provided, they will be used by
>   default on bulk items that don’t provide them explicitly.

So, the middle endpoint is valid, and it implies to me that a) you have to explicitly provide a type in the metadata for each document indexed, or b) that you can index documents into the default mapping ("_default_").

But I can't get this to work.

- I've tried the /myindex/bulk endpoint with no type specified in the metadata.
- I've tried it with "_type": "_default_" specified.
- I've tried /myindex/_default_/bulk.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `_default_` mapping. This is about falling back to the default type that you specify in the URL. You can do the following

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

However the following snippet is exactly the same

```
POST /test/type1/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

And you can mix this

```
POST foo/bar/_bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

In this example, one document would be indexed into `foo` and one into `test`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.  I don't have a "type1" type, or any other type, and I don't want to have to create a type just to use bulk indexing.  So the question remains: how do I use the _bulk index operation with no type?

Comment: every index operation has a type, independent from bulk. You cannot index a document without a type.